# one of my entities isn't saving in entity framework when I update through my repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two entities 'Student' and 'StudentImage'. I'm using MVC 5 and I have a form where the student fills out his/her profile with an image and then saves it to the student and studentimage table. When there is no previous student I can insert both the student and studentimage ok, but when my repository does an update only the student gets updated and the studentimage does NOT get updated.
*I've done a sql profiler check and it doesn't look like studentimage gets used in any of the update queries. Another thing is that it's not throwing any error. It finishes and returns to my view.

here are my entities

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string AspNetUserRefId { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentImage StudentImage { get; set; } //one-to-one

    // other members below
}

public class StudentImage
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; } // one-to-one
}
```

here is my update method in the repository for my student

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Student student)
{
    if (!context.Students.Any(u => u.AspNetUserRefId == student.AspNetUserRefId))
    {
        // New entity
        context.Students.Add(student);
    }
    else
    {
        // Existing entity
        context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Here is my posted controller method edit that does the saving

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditStudentViewModel studentViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            byte[] array;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                studentViewModel.StudentImageFileBase.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                array = ms.GetBuffer();
            } 

            var student = new Student
            {
                AspNetUserRefId = studentViewModel.AspNetUserRefId,
                CatchPhrase = studentViewModel.CatchPhrase,
                StartedPracticing = Convert.ToInt16(studentViewModel.SelectedYearId),
                Location = studentViewModel.Location,
                Education = studentViewModel.Education,
                Work = studentViewModel.Work,
                SelfDescription = studentViewModel.SelfDescription,
                Inspirations = studentViewModel.Inspirations,
                StudentId = studentViewModel.StudentId,
                StudentImage = new StudentImage { Image = array, StudentId = studentViewModel.StudentId}
            };

            studentRepository.InsertOrUpdate(student);
            studentRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Student");
        } else {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to also mark the attached image as being changed as well...

```
// Existing entity
context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.Entry(student.StudentImage).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

...as I do not think it will automatically propagate the modified state to the attached student image record. Assuming the .StudentImage instance is already part of the context. If not then you will need to add it.

Comment: then why does it propagate to studentimage if I'm inserting a row for the first time? Not an update but insert!

Comment: Because when you add a record it automatically performs an add for the entire tree of connected records. But when changing the state of an individual record it only ever changes that one record, it does not propagate automatically. That's just the way the Entity Framework is implemented.

Comment: ok understood! but adding context.Entry(student.StudentImage).State = EntityState.Modified; to my InsertUPdate in the repository just seemed a little bit NOT correct!? It seems like there is probably a better way that I'm unaware of because I'm kinda a newbie to EF.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to attach the entity to the context and then set the entry as modified?:

```
context.Set<Students>().Attach(student);
var entry = context.Entry(student);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

When editing data with the Entity Framework, the original objects need to be loaded so that changes can be applied.  You're doing that with `context.Entry(student)`; however, can you confirm that the related object `StudentImage` is being loaded, as well?

I noticed that you have the related object defined as `public virtual StudentImage StudentImage { get; set; }`.  EF uses Lazy Loading by default for `virtual` properties.  What happens when you take out the `virtual` keyword?

Assuming it's still active, this page has more information on [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

Comment: which part? do you mean the virtual declaration? or just the whole line? Remember I want a one-to-one relationship here

Comment: Try removing just the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: hi TLS. I removed the virtual and updated the db, but when I ran Find(string id) in my repo to get the student, it returned StudentImage as null. Where as before it returned StudentImage with Student, whether it was lazy loaded or not, I would guess and say lazy by default. So, unless there is something else I'm missing here. I will just go with Phile Wright's solution below. I checked other related posts and it seems to be the solution.

Comment: Appropriate. Be sure to accept his answer if it solves your problem.